# Prove or disprove: $A\in \mathbb{C}^{3\times 3}$ and $A^3+4A=0$ then $A$ is not invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Prove or disprove: $A\in \mathbb{C}^{3\times 3}$ and $A^3+4A=0$ then $A$ is not invertible. 

My work: 
If $A^3+4A=0$ then $A^3=-4A$, taking determinant on both sides we get $|A^3|=|-4A| \Rightarrow |A|^3=-64|A| \Rightarrow |A|^2=-64 \Rightarrow |A|=\sqrt {-64}\ne0$, so $A$ is invertible since $|A|\ne0.$

Would this be a valid proof that $A$ is indeed invertible and the statement is false? or do I need to come up with a counter example? (I'm struggling to do that with the requirments). 
Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: $z^3+64z=0\iff z(z^2+64)=0\iff z=0$ OR $z=\pm 8i$.

Comment: Consider diagonal matrices.

Comment: @TitoEliatron Appreciate the help, may I ask just about why is it allowed to hop to normal equation not with matrices to find the roots? and I'm wondering what mistake I did calculating the det that made me miss the zero root

Comment: @TitoEliatron Or was it a hint that can make me find a counter example using that $2^3=8$ in a diagonal matrix? Sorry about these silly questions, I'm a little worried I understand stuff in a wrong way :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an easier way to do this: Take $A$ to be of the form $A=\lambda I$, where $\lambda$ is nonzero and satisfies $$\lambda^3 +4\lambda =0.$$

Answer (score 5):

Here's a counterexample:
$$A = 2iI_3.$$

Comment: To motivate the answer somewhat. When a product of $n \times n$ matrices fails to be invertible, one of the factors must fail to be invertible. Because $A^3 + 4A = A(A^2 + 4I)$ it is thus possible to deduce from the given that at least one of $A$ and $A^2 + 4I$ fails to be invertible, but it doesn't automatically tell you that it's $A$ that has to fail to be invertible. Looking for simple examples of invertible matrices for which $A^2 + 4I$ isn't invertible may lead you here. Separately, it is generally a good idea to test any belief about $n \times n$ matrices with diagonal matrices.

Answer (score 2):

Write the given equation as $A(A^2+4)=0$. Then either $A^2+4I=0$ or there exists some vector $u$ so that $v=(A^2+4I)u$ is non-zero and thus a non-trivial kernel vector of $A$.

In the first case, $A$ is invertible, with inverse $-\frac14A$. In the second case a non-trivial kernel exists, so not invertible. With the given assumptions, both cases are possible.

Answer (score 1):

$A^3-4A = 0$ tells us that A has eigenvalues in $\{2i, -2i, 0\}$

If $0$ is an eigenvalue then $A$ is not invertible.  If $A$ were a real $3\times 3$ matrix, we must choose a real eigenvalue, zero is our only choice, and $A$ is singular.  However, if $A$ has complex entries, there is no reason that 0 must be an eigenvalue of our matrix.

$A = 2iI$ would be a counter-example.